# In Flex 4 is there a way to get all the classes in the domain?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

Is there a way to get all the classes in the current application. Say for example you create a blank Application and want to see all the classes that exist, this would list system manager, application, uicomponent, etc.

Comment: Not a proper answer, but I recall being able to enumerate the contents of `_global` to see the used/active classes at runtime.

Comment: @J_A_X - I'm working on an IDE and I'd like to get a list of all classes that are loaded. In some cases to create instances of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the list of classes in the domain is not made available by the standard Reflection API.

However, the [AS3 Commons Bytecode library](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/index.html) exists, which is able to read the Bytecode of the current app (or any bytecode for that matter) and parse it, providing access to all the current classes in the domain.  (Along with a whole bunch of other cool stuff).

There's an example showing how to do what you're after [here](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-bytecode/introduction.html).

The downside of using this library is that you have to re-load and parse the data at runtime, which has a significant performance cost.

James Ward and Mike Labriola did some work on modifying the SWF Loaders which load the initial bytecode into your flex app, so that the reflection is performed at startup, reducing the need to parse the bytecode twice.

James has blogged about his results [here](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/04/26/introducing-mixing-loom-runtime-actionscript-bytecode-modification/).